# Missing Django 0.96 Template documentation (used by Google AppEngine developers)

Tags: google-app-engine, django-templates

Django has removed their 0.96 version of the Django 0.96 Template documentation.

1. Does anyone have a mirror (or copy of some sort)
2. What version of Django Templates is Google AppEngine using (out of the box)

Answer (score 4):

I re-generated the documentation (seriously annoying, I had to check out just the right version of the djangoproject.com repository) and futzed with them a bit.

I have published them as a courtesy to other App Engine developers: [django096docs.appspot.com](http://django096docs.appspot.com/). Enjoy.

To answer your other question, App Engine uses Django 0.96 templates out of the box. Django 1.1 is also installed on the App Engine servers, but not distributed with the SDK. [You can enable that with `use_library`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django) but make sure to install it locally, too.

Comment: dude, you're a legend for uploading this. it's been far easier to use 0.96 than try and force my GAE app to use a more recent version of django. THANKS A MILLION!