# Master pages for GAE project (python)

Tags: google-app-engine

I've got a project running on GAE and I am quite sick of manual support of headers and footers in all the page templates I have.
Is there any way to use master pages for GAE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a `_base.htm` template with header and footer:

```
<!-- header -->
{% block bodycontent %}

{% endblock %}
<!-- footer -->
```

And expand it using specific templates:

```
{% extends "_base.htm" %}
{% block bodycontent %}  

<!-- template-specific stuff -->

{% endblock %}
```

#### Example

This is a template folder of my [cms-app on github](https://github.com/halst/keleshev-com/blob/master/templates/default.htm):

```
templates/
├── _404.htm
├── _base.htm
├── _edit.htm
├── _login.htm
├── _unavailable.htm
├── blog.htm
└── default.htm
```

Where blog.htm and default.htm templates extend the _base.htm template with headers, footers and counters.

#### Side note,

On my other app, which is not on github, I use naming convention with names like `search.foo.base.htm` which means that it's a templates that extends `foo.base.htm` template, which extends `base.htm` template - I think this is a useful tip if you have complex hierarchy of templates.

#### Documentation

GAE uses django templates version 0.96 (by default), which docs could not be found on djangoproject.com site. However, some good people put them online, see this question:
 [Missing Django 0.96 Template documentation (used by Google AppEngine developers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895848/missing-django-0-96-template-documentation-used-by-google-appengine-developers)

Comment: There's no reason to go with Django 1.2 templates. Create/edit `appengine_config.py` and add the line `webapp_django_version=1.2`

Comment: @DaveW.Smith, wow this one is useful, thanks for tip. I knew about `use_library()` but have not heard of `appengine_config.py' before!